# ¿Cómo mantener el formato de un archivo TXT en Excel con Python?

Tags: python, excel, txt, openpyxl

He desarrollado un método el cual permite convertir un archivo TXT a Excel, pero el problema es que sólo reconoce 1 columna en el archivo .xlsx. Habrá alguna manera de poder hacer que se mantenga el formato del archivo txt con columnas y filas en Excel?

Aquí dejo el código desarrollado:

```
def txt_to_xlsx(filename, outfile):
  fr = codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='latin1')
  wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
  ws = wb.active

  ws.title = 'Sheet1'

  ws = wb.create_sheet()

  row = 0
  for line in fr:
      row += 1
      line = line.strip()
      line = line.split('\t')
      col = 0
      for j in range(len(line)):
          col += 1
          #print (line[j])
          ws.cell(column=col, row=row, value=line[j].format(get_column_letter(col)))
  wb.save(outfile)
txt_to_xlsx('reporte.txt','reporte.xlsx')
```

El archivo txt:

```
Ref.:gc_k_lista_dif_mpe.spp                                                     
Fecha: 31-01-2011 22:37:28
Cia.:1  ADECSO PERU CIA DE SEG Y REAS.       LISTADO JUSTIFICATIVO ASIENTO 
IGV E INTERESES       Pag.:   1            
Fecha Proceso: 31-01-2011
Oficina .....: 1001 PROYECTOS ESPECIALES 
Moneda ......: 1 S/. 
Sector   Letra/Aviso  Rec/Fa/Nc  Poliza  Doc Cto.Venta   Intereses  Impuestos     

1   390838             13948619 1100610100076  FA       AV                  31.57                 57.15   FERNANDEZ MU¥OZ KARIN STEFANIE          
3   399430             15658428 3021010122380  FA       AV                    .00                 79.83   PROG.DE DESAR.DE SANIDAD AGROP-PRODESA  
3   399430             15658442 3021010122384  FA       AV                    .00                 79.83   PROG.DE DESAR.DE SANIDAD AGROP-PRODESA  
3   399430             15658468 3021010122382  FA       AV                    .00                 79.83   PROG.DE DESAR.DE SANIDAD AGROP-PRODESA  
3   399430             15658469 3021010122383  FA       AV                    .00                 79.83   PROG.DE DESAR.DE SANIDAD AGROP-PRODESA  
1   400242             14389758 1101030000008  FA       AV                  21.73                 41.54   B&J COMERCIAL MOLLENDO E.I.R.L.         
1   404456             15020777 1100720000002  FA       AV                  20.16                 38.01   MORALES GARCIA KARLA                    
1   408008             17338008 1141010101446  FA       AV                    .00                 15.96   MERCADO VARGAS CARLA CECILIA            
3   416775             18887812 3021012502503  FA       AV                    .00                  2.60   TAFUR SANTILLAN ROSA ISABEL             
1   420148             19335411 1100810400032  FA       AV                  28.46                 53.04   ASTETE CACERES MELISSA                  
1   421693             19722714 1141010800012  FA       AV                   7.96                 19.13   FUN AGAIN SRL                           
1   421693             19722869 1141010800010  FA       AV                  62.10                149.15   FUN AGAIN SRL                           
1   421694             19722715 1141010800012  FA       AV                   7.96                 19.13   FUN AGAIN SRL                           
1   421694             19722870 1141010800010  FA       AV                  62.10                149.15   FUN AGAIN SRL                           
1   422137             19760080 1141010700012  FA       AV                   3.53                  8.62   CHUECOS SANCHEZ LOURDES TERESA          
1   422137             19760102 1141010700011  FA       AV                  28.39                 69.37   CHUECOS SANCHEZ LOURDES TERESA          
1   424467             20146652 1100910100041  FA       AV                  67.21                159.26   ISASI CAYO JUAN FELIPE GUILLERMO        
1   426029             19706076 1141010400025  FA       AV                  19.01                 26.80   OTOYA PALMIERI IDA SILVANA
```

Comment: vuelvo a decir que por favor muestres el archivo `.txt` o una parte, asi sabremos como están los datos

Comment: Ok Christian, adjunto el .txt

Comment: yo no soy tan exigente como otros, te dirán que coloques el `txt` como texto, pero por mi esta bien para trabajar en la respuesta

Comment: Lo acabo de editar como texto

Comment: perfecto, facilitas el trabajo a mi y a los demás que quieran ayudar

Comment: te interesa todos los datos? o solo los de las filas y columnas?

Comment: En cuanto a las filas sí me sale de forma correcta, pero el detalle son las columnas, ya que sería óptimo que se muestren en Excel la misma cantidad de columnas del txt

Comment: Bueno tengo echo el mas del 50% mañana publico la respuesta, por aqui ya es tarde (aunque tu también eres de Perú)

Comment: Esta bien Christian, perfecto, thanks

Comment: ¿El TXT siempre tiene el mismo formato?

Comment: @Christian en este caso hay razones para ser "estricto" con el tema de las imagenes. 1) si alguien esta en un telefono por ejemplo, se le haria dificil ver las letras de la imagen. 2) gente con navegadores especiales o conexiones lentas no podran ver la imagen. Toda esta gente pierde la posibilidad de responder la pregunta por que al usuario se le ocurrio poner una imagen de su txt.

Comment: @DanteS. lo siento, vi que este usuario hizo varias publicaciones con el mismo problema, así que decidí ayudarlo como sea. Creo que para la próxima voy a ser un poco mas *exigente*

Comment: Siempre es bueno evitar los excesos. Ni muy estricto ni poco exigente (me equivoque de palabra y casi lo vuelvo a hacer, no se por que) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Haaa.. me demore mas de lo que pensaba, nunca había trabajado con un `txt`. Para mi respuesta utilizo pandas para el manejo de los datos, puesto que así simplemente creamos el *DataFrame* y luego convertimos a *Excel*, es mucho mas fácil y cómodo de  manejar.

Primero instalamos pandas

```
pip install pandas
```

```py
#importanmos pandas
import pandas as pd

#leemos el archivo
df = pd.read_fwf('archivo.txt',header=None)

#aqui establecemos el nombre de las columnas
cols =['Sector','Letra/Aviso','Rec/Fa/Nc','Poliza','Doc Cto.Venta','Intereses','Impuestos','','Nombres']
```

Al leer el txt con Pandas nos devuelve un objeto de tipo *DataFrame*, sien embargo al no haber una estructura especifica de datos (columna y filas), el DataFrame es es muy confuso, ademas como solo necesitamos los datos de la *"matriz"* (las filas y columnas de datos) solo vamos a escoger esos datos, ¿Cómo lo hacemos?, pues fácil, esos datos se encuentran en la fila 9 de nuestro *DataFrame* Para eso utilizamos la función `loc[inicio:fin]` el cual cogerá las filas que le digamos en este caso `8:` esto quiere decir desde la fila 9 hasta el final.

```py
#cogemos los datos necesarios
datos = df.loc[8:]
```

Un problema que note, es que tu archivo TXT no tiene definidas el nombre de todas las columnas, mas específicamente las 2 ultimas columnas no tienen una *"etiqueta"* lo que provoca que no tengamos los datos correctamente.

Cuando pasa esto, pandas asigna el valor de `NaN`(Not a Number), lo que genera una lista de esos valores, aparte de la que ya se creo, para eso tenemos que coger los datos *"manualmente"*

```py
#obtenemos los datos "fragmentados"
#obtenemos los datos "fragmentados"
data = list(datos[0]) #datos con su etiqueta correcta
numeros = list(datos[1]) #La primera columna de numeros 
numeros2 = list(datos[2])#la segunda columna de numero
nombres = list(datos[3]) #la columna que contiene nombres
```

Ahora bien, so hacemmos un `print()` de la variable `data` obtenemos esto:

```
['1   390838             13948619 1100610100076  FA       AV',
'3   399430             15658428 3021010122380  FA       AV',
'3   399430             15658442 3021010122384  FA       AV',
'3   399430             15658468 3021010122382  FA       AV',
...]
```

Como ves esto son los datos, pero están separados por espacios, *"empaquetar"* estos datos en una lista (haciendo referencia a una fila) usaremos el método `split()`, este método por defecto separara la cadena por espacios, sin importar el numero de espacios.

Para hacer esto nos ayudaremos de un ciclo `for` para recorrer cada dato, para abreviar utilizaremos una *"compresión de lista"*, lo que se puede interpretar como un ciclo `for` en una lista.

```py
#quitamos los espacios en blanco
separation_data = [dato.split() for dato in data]
```

Bien hasta ahora todo esto fue fácil, ahora viene lo difícil, ¿Cómo manejamos los datos que no tienen una columna con nombre?, estos datos ya lo hemos separado antes y están en las variable `numeros`, `numeros2`, `nombres`. Pero ¿Qué hacemos?, si imprimimos la variable `separation_data` obtenemos:

```
[
['1', '390838', '13948619', '1100610100076', 'FA', 'AV'], 
['3', '399430', '15658428', '3021010122380', 'FA', 'AV'],
...
]
```

Donde vemos que cada lista representa a una fila, pero no una fila completa, ya que falta los datos *"sin columna"*. Lo que tendremos que hacer es agregar cada dato de cada columna a cada lista, para esto nos ayudamos de la función `zip()` y una *compresión de lista*

```
#agregamos todo a la lista principal
[lista.append(num) for lista, num in zip(separation_data, numeros)]
[lista.append(num) for lista, num in zip(separation_data, numeros2)]
[lista.append(name) for lista, name in zip(separation_data, nombres)]

#asignamos un mejor nombre a los nuevos datos
data = separation_data
```

Lo que hace `zip()` es unir las listas, esto nos devolverá una tupla `(lista, elemento)`, donde `lista` es cada lista (fila) y `elemento` es  cada elemento de la lista *sin columna* que asignemos (ya sea `numeros`, `numeros2` o `nombres`).

En este caso le asignamos un resultado a esa *compresión de lista*, ya que internamente se esta modificando la variable `separation_data`

Finalmente convertimos todo eso a un *DataFrame* y lo convertimos a un Excel, son el método `to_excel()` de pandas, lo unico que tines que especificar es el nombre con que va ha ser guardado

```py
#generamos el DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)
# df.to_excel('name.xlsx')
print(df)
```

Si no entendiste o comprendiste bien algo, avísame y tratare de explicarlo

Comment: Gracias Christian, una pregunta, y si en caso en alguna columna del TXT los registros tuvieran una separación así: "100110111000065/  1" , cómo podría hacer para que lo reconozca como un campo y la función "split()" no lo separe en 2 campos.

Agradecería me puedas orientar en ello

Comment: @AndersonFuentes no estoy seguro que los separe, pues `split()` por defecto separa los vacios `' '`, saltos de lineas `\n` y `\t`, pero para evitar confusiones, creo que se podría armar una expresión regular

Comment: @AndersonFuentes no olvides aceptar la respuesta si te fue de ayuda